# ASP.NET Query string second value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, query-string

I have a grid with link button and on RowDatabound:

```
lbutton.Attributes.Add("onclick",
    "javascript:window.showModalDialog('Showsome.aspx?ID=" + lbutton.CommandArgument + " &IsMA=M" +
    "','window.self','dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:800px;center:yes; status:yes; scroll:no; help:no');");
```

I am able to retrieve ID from `Request.QueryString["ID"]`;
However, I am not able to retrieve `Request.QueryString["IsMA"]`

How can this be achieved?

I tried the suggestions, no more spaces and did URL encode and I am not getting the value correctly. I have another approach since it is a hardcoded value 'M' that is needed along with the value I am now appending it in ID value itself `'Showsome.aspx?ID=M"` . Thanks for you support.

Comment: can you paste your URL, probably you need to encode string to html "lbutton.CommandArgument"

Comment: you probably need to URL-encode the command argument.

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: My Bad! I had lbutton.Attributes.Add and another linkbutton and accidentally again had lbutton.Attributes.Add which overwrote my actual code. so I have picked out the first answer. I guess all the suggestion here work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a space between the `CommandArgument` and `&IsMA`

Could this be causing your problem?

Try:

```
+ lbutton.CommandArgument + "&IsMA=M"
```

What is `CommandArgument` value? You may need to encode this. I would recommend doing this either way.

```
+ Server.UrlEncode(lbutton.CommandArgument) + "&IsMA=M"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the space before the ampersand character:

```
lbutton.CommandArgument + "&IsMA=M"
```

**EDIT:** As SLaks points out below, escaping the ampersand character is not necessary. Accordingly, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.add.aspx) for `Attributes.Add()` says:

> If the string in the `value` parameter contains an ampersand (`&`), the
>   character is automatically encoded. The resulting HTML representation
>   is "`&amp;`".

Comment: ASP.Net should do that for him.

Comment: Escaping the ampersand? Maybe. Removing the space? I'm not so sure :)

Comment: I've known of some issues with spaces before depending on the browser. A lot of older browsers would not read spaces and would require encoding. Never had an issue with `&` not being converted in a server ran control before though..